# Formatos de fechas en Español MySQL

Tags: mysql

Quiero dar formato a una fecha para que el resultado sea de la siguiente manera:

```
15 - Ene - 2017
```

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(nacimiento,'%d %M %Y') as 'F. Nacimiento' FROM tabla;
```

El resultado me arroja lo siguiente:

> 15 - January - 2017

Quiero que me muestre las 3 primeras letras del mes pero en Español.

Comment: Es posible que adjuntes el codigo de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Porque no esta claro si lo deseas hacer en MySQL o quieres que sea solo PHP

Comment: Quiero hacerlo en MySQL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Codigo

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%d - %b - %Y') AS fecha FROM ejemplo;
```

---

#### Resultado

```
27 - ago - 2017
```

---

### Explicacion

En la [documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html) de MySQL respectiva al uso de los locales, puedes encontrar la variable `lc_time_names`, la cual contiene el formato de locales que podra ser usado para tus consultas.

Algunos de estos formatos pueden ser:

```
es_AR: Spanish - Argentina   ||  es_BO: Spanish - Bolivia
es_CL: Spanish - Chile       ||  es_CO: Spanish - Columbia
es_CR: Spanish - Costa Rica  ||  es_DO: Spanish - Dominican Republic
es_EC: Spanish - Ecuador     ||  es_ES: Spanish - Spain
es_GT: Spanish - Guatemala   ||  es_HN: Spanish - Honduras
es_MX: Spanish - Mexico      ||  es_NI: Spanish - Nicaragua
es_PA: Spanish - Panama      ||  es_PE: Spanish - Peru
es_PR: Spanish - Puerto Rico ||  es_PY: Spanish - Paraguay
```

Basta cambiarlo a un valor en Español, que sea de preferencia de tu pais o bien un formato general, para este caso hemos puesto Español de España (es_ES).

Respecto al tipo de formato que se debe usar para obtener la abreviacion del mes, puedes mirar en el listado de [formateadores](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) para `date_format()` alli podras ver que existe uno, cuyo valor es `%b`, cuya utilidad, segun la documentacion es:

> **%b**    Abbreviated month name (Jan to Dec)

En una traduccion vaga del texto:

> **%b**    Nombre del mes abreviado (Ene to Dic)

Lo cual nos permite obtener el formato de fecha deseado.

---

### [Ejemplo en linea!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/620ba/6)

Comment: En que parte agrego esta linea. SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';  Ya me muestras las 3 letras del mes pero en ingles

Comment: @Scorpion Antes de realizar la consulta de fecha

Comment: No me funciona, esta es la consulta:   $consulta = "SELECT id_jugador, documento, concat(nombres, ' ', apellidos) as 'Nombre', DATE_FORMAT(nacimiento,'%d-%b-%Y'), celular, DATE_FORMAT(registro,'%d-%m-%Y') as 'F. Registro' FROM jugador;";

Comment: Antes de realizar la consulta, has agregado la linea?

Comment: si de este modo:  SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES' ;
                        $consulta = "SELECT id_jugador, documento, concat(nombres, ' ', apellidos) as 'Nombre', DATE_FORMAT(nacimiento,'%d-%b-%Y'), celular, DATE_FORMAT(registro,'%d-%m-%Y') as 'F. Registro' FROM jugador;";    pero me da error en esa linea del SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';

Comment: Intenta con SET GLOBAL lc_time_names = 'es_ES';

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64510/discussion-between-ivan-botero-and-scorpion).

Comment: Desde php tienes que realizar 2 consultas, 1 para establecer el localismo y otra para la consulta en si mismo, o en su defecto usar mysqli_multi_query().