# Convertir mes numero en mes letra

Tags: php

Tengo esta linea de texto para mandar llamar de mi base de datos un dato de una columna y uso el substr para que solo muestre el 01 de 2018-01-05T14:00.

Mi pregunta es como puedo convertir ese 01 que me muestra a mes en letra y asi sucesivamente el 02, 03, etc.

```
<h2><?php $mes = substr($fechamovimiento, 5, -9);?> <?php echo $mes;?></h2>
```

Comment: nos muestras por favor que has intentado?

Comment: <h2><?php $mes = substr($fechamovimiento, 5, -9);?> <?php echo $mes;?></h2>

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si esta respuesta te sirve, la traducimos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18467892/73749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el ejemplo que pongo cree un array con los meses, vos podes modificar las palabras y mostrar lo que vos quieras:

```
<?php
        $fechamovimiento =  "2018-12-05T14:00";
        $meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
        $mes = substr($fechamovimiento, 5, -9);
        if ($mes <= 12) {
            echo $meses[$mes - 1];
        }
        else{
            echo "Solo existen 12 meses hay un error en el formato de tu fecha: ".$fechamovimiento;
        }
```

Basicamente lo que haces es crear un array con las palabras, luego como ya tenes el mes separado de la fecha que es un numero vas y lo buscas dentro del array restandole uno ya que si tenes el mes 3 seria Marzo pero en tu array Marzo esta en la posicion 2 por que los array empiezan de 0, ya si por error te llega un mes mayor a 12 puse un mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, brother!!!!!

Comment: Si te sirvió no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta. Slds.-

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @Juan es la correcta. Pero si lo estas tomando de una base de datos SQL seguramente puedas hacer que la base te entregue el mes en castellaño.
[Aca hay una repuesta sobre como hacerlo en MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/97734/7424)

Comment: Me lo entrega en español el resultado.

Comment: y lo necesitas de otra forma? o es una pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Yo sé que ha pasado tiempo pero yo he usado las siguientes líneas para modificar la fecha, separarla y transformarla a los nombres de los meses sin necesidad de tanto rollo:

```
<?php
 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');//Para la fecha en español castellano
 $fechamovimiento =  strtotime("2018-12-05T14:00");
 $f = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', date("m", $fechamovimiento));
 $mes = strftime("%B", $f->getTimestamp());
 $dia = date("d", $fechamovimiento);                    
 $anio = date("Y", $fechamovimiento);
 $hora = date("H", $fechamovimiento);
 $minutos = date("i", $fechamovimiento);
 $segundos = date("s", $fechamovimiento);
?>
```

Espero que a alguien le funcione si ve ésta respuesta. Se puede también hacer el "strtotime" a las variables de nuestra consulta de sql.
Yo lo aprendí de [aquí](https://www.bufa.es/php-convertir-un-numero-al-nombre-del-mes-en-espanol/)