# consulta en sql para obtener mi cupon siempre y cuando el id del evento sea el mismo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente consulta la cual dentro del select muestra si el cupon existe en la base de datos y si aun es vigente pero yo quiero ver si hay una forma de que se haga por evento por ejemplo en la consulta le paso el id_evento y en la tabla precios donde se encuentra mi cupon tengo un campo llamado fk_id_evento que hace referencia al id_evento para saber de que evento es ese precio y si el evento no hace march quisiera que no lo mostrara

```
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_MX.UTF-8');
    $vigencia_fin = strftime("%d %b %Y", strtotime('.$vigencia_fin.'));
   
    $date_now = date('Y-m-d');
    $cupon = (string)$_POST['cupon'];
    $id_evento = (string)$_POST['id_evento'];
    $to = date('2020-09-22');


    $result = $connexion->query(


    'SELECT * FROM precios WHERE cupon = "'.$cupon.'" and vigencia_fin Between "'.$date_now.'" and "'.$to.'"  '
         // 'SELECT * FROM precios WHERE cupon = "'.$cupon.'" and vigencia_fin Between "2018-01-01" and "2020-09-02" and fk_id_precios = "'.$id_evento.'" '

    );
        if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $precio=$row["precios_id"];
              $preciomx=$row["preciomx"]; 
               $vigencia_fin=$row["vigencia_fin"];

   echo '<div class="alert " style="margin-top: 1%">
    Vigente al '.$preciomx.' '.$vigencia_fin.'
```

y tambien quiero que mi vigencia_fin se muestre en formato string por ejemplo 14 agosto 2020 pero no se como hacerlo

en el select intente hacer esto pero no me funciona

```
'SELECT * FROM precios WHERE cupon = "'.$cupon.'" and vigencia_fin Between "'.$date_now.'" and "'.$to.'" and fk_id_precios Between "'.$id_evento.'" and "fk_id_precios" '
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que tienes una segunda tabla llamada evento y de ahí seleccionas el id_evento, el cual quieres utilizar para filtrar tus registros de la tabla precios, si es asi creo que esto te serviría

SELECT * FROM precios WHERE **fk_id_evento= "'.$id_evento.'" and** cupon = "'.$cupon.'" and vigencia_fin Between "'.$date_now.'" and "'.$to.'"  '

para tu segunda pregunta esto puede ayudar
[Formatos de fechas en Español MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97732/formatos-de-fechas-en-espa%C3%B1ol-mysql)

Comment: el filtro si me funciono pero el de la fecha me sigue sin dar aun tengo problemas no se como implementarlo

Comment: debes configurar la variable regional usada configurar el idioma de días y meses SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'; después en tu consulta debes usar esto  DATE_FORMAT(tu_fecha, '%d %M %Y') esto debes usarlo entre el select y el from

Comment: $originalDate = "2017-03-08";
$newDate = strftime("%d %M %Y", strtotime($originalDate)); hice algo asi pero no me funciona